# ubuntu android sdk location can not be at the filesystem root

Tags: android, ubuntu-sdk

I have the "Ubuntu android sdk location can not be at the filesystem root" Error with android studio :

[image]

in this os :

```
so@sosa:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch)
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

I have tried google it and don't find any solution, so Would you mind, help me to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click on **Edit** just beside the **Android SDK Location** box

[image]

You'd be redirected to a window with a couple of components to install, and a new location automatically selected for where to install them. Go ahead and install, and take note of your new SDK location
[image]

Comment: Thanks... Helped me a lot...

Comment: if nothing happens, change the location in SDK Component Setup (screen shot 2), then it will refresh and download